# What is the meaning of "cropped sensor"?

Tags: dslr, terminology, sensor, cropped-sensor, sensor-size

What is the meaning of the term "cropped sensor"?

Comment: See also [What are the different sensor sizes used in DSLRs?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2801/1943), and also [tag:cropped-sensor].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you just record a part of the image, hence crop...

A full frame sensor is 36mmx24mm in size, a cropped sensor, in the case of Canon APS-C approximately 27,9mmx18,6mm.

Lenses are typically designed to throw an image circle with a diameter of 56mm to cover old wet film - or the equally sized full frame sensor.
A crop sensor that sits the same distance away, covers a smaller area of the image circle and hence records only a portion of the image circle thrown - i.e. it crops the image thrown by the lens.

Comment: Why 56mm and not 43.3?

Comment: Also, what is "wet film"?

Comment: Because lenses tend to darken towards corners known as vignetting, hence the image circle needs to be larger than the diagonal of the sensor. Wet film = old analog film.

Comment: And (sorry for so many questions!) since the image circle is cropped to a rectangle by film or a full frame sensor, and needs to cut out that vignetting, why don't we call _that_ a cropped sensor too?

Comment: Well, technically a "full frame" sensor is a cropped sensor compared to medium format ;).

It really is a bit of a "traditionalist" phrase. 35mm film established itself as the "medium of choice" for most photographers and became the defacto standard around which all terminology centers. If we refer to a standard lens we refer to 50mm on "full frame" rather than 50mm on say medium format (which preceded the 35mm film).

Introducing digital sensors, the sensor were downsized, but the terminology stayed the same. Then came the full frame sensors, equivalent to 35mm film.

Comment: With digital full frame sensors and the remaining terminology retained, we just accepted anything that is smaller to be a "crop sensor".
At the same time, camera manufacturers also needed a way to describe their smaller sensors and decided "crop" with respect to the 35mm film "standard" was a good way to do so and the term since stuck.

Comment: Would it be possible to have lenses throwing an image circle smaller than 56mm (and thus, have smaller sensors behaving as full-frame), or this is just a physics problem?

Comment: You can have a lens that throws a smaller image circle, but that does not change the focal length. It also won't change the behaviour of the sensor with regards to being "full frame". Just look at EF-S lenses - they do exactly that, throw a smaller image circle. Look at Medium format and a 50mm lens throws a larger image circle, but it does not change the focal length.

Answer (score 5):

A "crop" sensor is a sensor (usually in a DLSR) that is smaller than the standard 35mm film size. 35mm sensors are referred to as "full frame". Images produced from a "crop" sensor are equivalent to the middle being cropped out of a "full frame" sensor image.

I don't really like either term - the 35mm frame size is wholly arbitrary, provided the viewfinder shows you the correct field of view then it doesn't matter that the sensor is smaller than 35mm - "full frame" sensors are in tern smaller than 645 medium format sensors, which are smaller than large format sensors etc.

Comment: I wouldn't call it arbitrary, for it was a doubling of the normal movie image by Barnack. Now, one could argue that the film size was arbitrary at one point, but the film decision was based on existing media, and thus, not arbitrary.